# How can I install the X11 version of Firefox on Snow Leopard? (Preferably without MacPorts or Fink?)

Tags: snow-leopard, macports, firefox, x11, fink

I’m doing some screen-scraping using Selenium, a framework which lets you programmatically control web browsers on your system. I’m running it as part of a web app on a Linux server, and on my MacBook Pro for when I’m writing the web app.

On my server, Selenium uses Firefox headlessly (by using Xvfb instead of a real display). I’d like to do the same thing locally, so that I don’t have Firefox windows popping up all the time whilst I’m writing and testing Selenium code. In order to do this, I need to install the X11 version of Firefox on my Mac.

I’ve seen a lot of references to MacPorts and Fink, but is there a way to just install the X11 version of Firefox, rather than installing MacPorts or Fink just for this one-off?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you shying away from MacPorts? I can't speak for Fink, but I always put MacPorts on my machines right away so I can use get ports when I need to. If I get an app for one-time use, I usually just uninstall it after I'm done with it.

Comment: 1. The website was down for a while today when I was trying to look into it — didn’t inspire confidence. 2. I get the feeling that both MacPorts and Fink are a bit hard to remove afterwards, and generally a bit faffy and not very Mac-like. (See [MacPorts’ uninstall instructions](http://guide.macports.org/#installing.macports.uninstalling) and Fink’s [“Fink is not a one-click-and-done thing”](http://www.finkproject.org/download/srcdist.php)). I’d prefer a binary I can stick in /usr/local/bin and forget about — not sure if that’s realistic for an app like Firefox though.

Comment: Removing fink is `rm -fR /sw` and nothing else should remain.

Comment: If this is possible, and I think it is a big if, it is likely to be very complex. I don't know why MacPorts was down, and I am a fink not MacPorts user, but I have high confidence in both those apps. There is a big community. They aren't going anywhere anytime soon.

Comment: As for "not Mac-like"... you want to run X11 apps, Xvfb, etc. I'm not understanding why something un-mac-ish is a problem.

Comment: @mankoff: sure, I see your point. It’s just that most of the stuff I run at the command line is just a single binary that I download and shove into /usr/local/bin. It’s cool if MacPorts/Fink is the best way to go.

Comment: Firefox requires a Window library to be linked with e.g. QT, Gnome and so will need a lot of other code so using Macports/Fink would save time

Comment: @Mark: sure, cool cool. If anyone wants to pop that in as an answer, we can consider this question done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firefox requires a Window library to be linked with e.g. QT, Gnome and several other C libraries. Thus to build it will need a lot of other code so I think using Homebrew/Macports/Fink would save time.

If you want any other X11 apps then Homebrew/Macports/Fink is likely to be the easiest way to get them.

Also as per @Nathan G. I have found installing Macports not to be difficult.

Comment: Nowadays [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) is the best alternative for MacPorts/Fink.

Comment: @ᴠɪɴᴄᴇɴᴛ why - I still think macports is better - first as it issues its own user and directory - until hombrew fixes that I can't look at it - but agreed it should be listed as an alternative

Comment: Indeed I mainly wanted to mention it as a serious alternative. ‘Best’ is subjective. I prefer it because of the user experience and the broadness of its ‘recipes’ (applications available for installation).